# Clear method is getting undefined for TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native

I just started working over ReactNative and I am developing an application that has an single `TextInput` with a `Button` in header. I am trying to `clear` textinput on button click but it's not working. And when I console `clear`, it is getting undefined. Here's my code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, AlertIOS, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard } from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../res/value/Colors';
import Styles from '../res/value/Styles';

import TouchableText from '../component/TouchableText';
import TouchableImage from '../component/TouchableImage';

export default class AddViewPin extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pin: ''
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const {params} = navigation.state;
    return{
      headerRight: (
          <TouchableImage
          style = {Styles.headerButtonRight}
          source = {require('../res/image/ic_save.png')}
          onPress = {() => params.handleSave && params.handleSave()}/>
      )
    }
  }

  savePin = () => {
    if (this.state.pin == ''){
      console.log('Your thoughts can\'t be empty!');
    } else {
      console.log(this.state.pin);
      console.log(this.textInputPin.clear());
      this.textInputPin.clear();
    }
  }

  onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({handleSave: () => this.savePin()});
  }

  handlePin = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      pin: text
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style = {{flex: 1}} >
        <TextInput
          onChangeText = {this.handlePin}
          ref={input => { this.textInputPin = input }}
          returnKeyType = 'done'
          blurOnSubmit = {true}
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.onSubmitHandler(event)}
          placeholder = 'Pin your out of the box thoughts here...'
          multiline = {true}
          style = {styles.textInput} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 4,
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add value prop to your textinput.

```
<TextInput value= {this.state.pin} />
```

Now your textinput getting pin from state so if you want to clear textinput just setState with empty text.

```
this.setState({
     pin: ''
})
```

Comment: But this is showing `this.state.pin` in textinput as a text on start application ?

Comment: Pin is empty in your initial state. It shouldnt show text. It should show your placeholder.